# Cannot set JAVA_HOME after installing opendjk with snap

Tags: java, environment-variables, openjdk

I installed openjdk with `sudo snap install openjdk`, and
I want to set `JAVA_HOME` to enable my `java` related commands in terminal, but it is not working.

I tried the following:

1. creating a script `java_home.sh` in `/etc/profile.d` with the content `JAVA_HOME=/snap/openjdk/current/jdk` and doing logout/login, but it is not working
2. creating a script `java_home.sh` in `/etc/profile.d` with the content `source $(openjdk)` and doing logout/login, but it is not working
3. adding `JAVA_HOME=/snap/openjdk/current/jdk export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME` to `~/.bashrc`, and opening new terminal, but it is still not working

I don't know what to try, or what to do, so if anyone can help, I will be very thankful.

The output of `ls /snap/openjdk` is `909  current`.

The output of `cat $(openjdk)` is:

```
# Source this file for OpenJDK environment variables and aliases
export JAVA_HOME=/snap/openjdk/909/jdk
export MANPATH=/snap/openjdk/909/jdk/man:
alias java='openjdk.java'
alias javac='openjdk.javac'
alias javadoc='openjdk.javadoc'
alias jar='openjdk.jar'
alias jarsigner='openjdk.jarsigner'
alias jlink='openjdk.jlink'
alias jpackage='openjdk.jpackage'
alias jwebserver='openjdk.jwebserver'
```

when doing `source openjdk`, it starts working, but I don't want to do that every time and want it loaded everywhere as a env variable.

Answer (score 3):

found the solution in developpaper.com

```bash
sudo snap install openjdk

openjdk 

//generate .env
// in my case /var/snap/openjdk/1005/openjdk.env

/**
# Source this file for OpenJDK environment variables and aliases
export JAVA_HOME=/snap/openjdk/1005/jdk
export MANPATH=/snap/openjdk/1005/jdk/man:
alias java='openjdk.java'
alias javac='openjdk.javac'
alias javadoc='openjdk.javadoc'
alias jar='openjdk.jar'
alias jarsigner='openjdk.jarsigner'
alias jlink='openjdk.jlink'
alias jpackage='openjdk.jpackage'
alias jwebserver='openjdk.jwebserver'
*/

add .env in to file /etc/profile 

source /etc/profile

java --version

openjdk 18.0.2 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2+9-snap)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2+9-snap, mixed mode, sharing)
```

https://developpaper.com/linux-system-uses-snap-to-install-jdk/

Answer (score 0):

Everything that the OS needs to find java is in `/snap/openjdk/909` or `/snap/openjdk/current` directories, it just needs the right paths.

So the answer to the quesiton:

Create `java_home.sh` in `/etc/profile.d/` and in the sh add:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/snap/openjdk/909/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

login/logout and `java --version` will work.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to 'source' /var/snap/openjdk/current/openjdk.env to /etc/bash.bashrc. Since you can sudo, I assume that you can edit it with nano.

```
sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Then, at the bottom of the file, source the env file by typing

```
source /var/snap/openjdk/current/openjdk.env
```

Using 'current', instead of the version number, is a good practice. In the future, if you update OpenJDK, that 'current' will still work. Also, there is no need to log off or restart. Any newly opened terminal or application that relies on bashrc will get the aliases and exports.

Note: instead of editing /etc/bash.bashrc, you may choose to edit ~/.bashrc if you prefer to make it visible only to your account.